# Weak failure trace when using page object pattern with spock and geb

Tags: spock, geb

When using spock+geb you can assert that you are on expected page by assertion e.g.:

```
assert title == 'Sign In'
```

and you get a nice failure trace if assertion fails:

```
Condition not satisfied:

title == 'Sign In'
|     |
Login false
      5 differences (28% similarity)
      (Lo)g(i--)n
      (Si)g(n I)n
```

But if I try to use page object pattern e.g.:

```
class LoginPage extends GebPage {
    static at = { title == 'Sign In' }
}
```

Trace is not very helping what's going wrong:

```
Condition not satisfied:

at(LoginPage)
|
false
```

Is there any way how to use page object pattern and get more descriptive failure trace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [geb mailing list responses](http://markmail.org/message/3r7jw5bsc4qfi24i) the current workaround is:

```
static at = { assert title == 'Sign In'; true }
```

Thanks to David & Luke.

Comment: As of version geb:0.9.0-RC-1, you can write static at = { assert title == 'Sign In' } and get the descriptive failure trace

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, I'm not sure if I have an answer to your question.  I believe I had a similar question at some point, but other issues became more important after time (such as the fact that WebDriver is a POS).  You won't find Stackoverflow to be much use when it comes to new & emerging libraries, such as Geb.

Your best bet is to post a message on Geb's mailing list instead.  You can find it [here](http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/geb/lists).

Luke Daley, the creator of Geb, usually responds to messages on a daily basis & is extremely helpful.  The mailing list is quite useful, even though the number of members is small at this point.

Comment: Thanks, my question has been just answered in the mailing list (see my answer).